# How do I change this JSON string to a specific format?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I am passing a string from view to controller. Here's my ajax code

```
    var formData = $('#spec-wip-form, #platingspec-form').serializeArray();
    var platingId = @Model.PlatingId;

    var form = JSON.stringify(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Specifications/Edit",
        type: 'PUT',
        data: { form, cleaningProcess, platingId },
        success: function () {
            onUpdated();
        }
    });
```

The JSON format I'm getting looks like this

```
"[{\"name\":\"PlatingId\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"name\":\"DivisionId\",\"value\":\"79\"}]
```

**I want it to look like this**

```
"[{\"PlatingId\":\"1\"},{\"DivisionId\":\"79\"}]
```

I already tried this earlier but

```
var formData = $('#spec-wip-form, #platingspec-form').serialize();
```

I get

```
formData: PlatingId=1&DivisionId=79&
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure it shoudn’t be `"[{\"PlatingId\":\"1\",\"DivisionId\":\"79\"}]`, i.e. both objects combined into one?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. I'm not getting the format I want.

Comment: Related: [Convert array of objects to object of key-value pairs](/q/61297000/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SebastionSimon for the correction. Also, this isn't double stringified to match your expected result. You can always run it through JSON.stringify a second time to match.

```js
let json = '[{"name":"PlatingId","value":"1"},{"name":"DivisionId","value":"79"}]';

let newjson = JSON.stringify(
    JSON.parse(json).map(
        ({name, value}) => ({[name]: value})
        ))

console.log(newjson)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Object.fromEntries() to create a single object.

```js
const formData = [{"name":"PlatingId","value":"1"},{"name":"DivisionId","value":"79"}];

const res = Object.fromEntries(formData.map(({name,value})=> [name, value]));

console.log(res)
```